# SAPPER : Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined

Tags: svelte, sapper

My website (https://www.romaingle.com/) works well when runnning on a localhost but when I go online and refresh any route the page does not show and I get this error :

```
portfolio_VCA_little_jewels.portfolio_VCA_little_jewels.js:487 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: 
Cannot read property 'title' of undefined
    at create_fragment (portfolio_VCA_little_jewels.portfolio_VCA_little_jewels.js:487)
    at init (main.js:2104)
    at new VCA_little_jewels (portfolio_VCA_little_jewels.portfolio_VCA_little_jewels.js:856)
    at Array.create_else_block (main.js:3810)
    at Array.create_default_slot (main.js:3933)
    at create_slot (main.js:738)
    at create_fragment (main.js:4551)
    at init (main.js:2104)
    at new Layout (main.js:4702)
    at create_fragment (main.js:4003)
```

Apparently there is a problem in the some_project.svelte page when I try to retrieve the data from a static store :

```
<script>
const { page } = stores();
  $folioData.forEach(element => {
    if (element.projectUrl == $page.path) data = element;
  });
</script>
```

Here is a [REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/a2b1ff734fe346cfa4d5cc42f6559e57?version=3.23.2) where I added the two files involved. The thing I really don't understand is that it works locally (even with a throttle) but not online...

Comment: You're going to need to provide way more details (and probably a [repro](http://sscce.org/)) before anyone is able to help you

Comment: Ok thanks for the feedback. It is going to be a lot of work but I'll try to do that. I added the link to my website if that can help...

Comment: Well here's a clue to start with — looks like you have some code like this... 

```
$folioData.forEach(element => {
  if (element.projectUrl == $page.path) data = element;
});
```

...and `data` is ending up undefined, because nothing exactly matches (maybe a case of a missing closing slash, or something. And the `<title>` of the page is `data.title`, if I'm not mistaken. So you need to try and figure out why the page isn't matching the contents of `$folioData`. Sweet-looking site btw :)

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I added a REPL with the files involved... It's difficult for me to explore as I don't know how to export in dev mode and put it online...